# Prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, it holds that for all real numbers $a,b\geq 0$, that $(\frac{a+b}{2})^n \leq \frac{a^n+b^n}{2}$

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm pretty new to proof by induction and I just wanted to see how I would prove something with multiple variables. Thanks.

Prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, it holds that for all real numbers $a,b\geq 0$, that $(\frac{a+b}{2})^n \leq \frac{a^n+b^n}{2}$

Comment: The recurrence hypothesis is "for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R},\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^n\leqslant\frac{a^n+b^n}{2}$".

Comment: @Tuvasbien Are you sure you want to use $\Bbb R$ rather than $[0,\,\infty)$?

Comment: @RichardPhan Welcome to Math SE. Note another basic duplicate is [how to prove the inequality $\sqrt[n]{\frac{a^n+b^n}{2}}\geq\frac{a+b}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2465303/602049).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a\mapsto ca,\,b\mapsto cb$ multiplies both sides by $c^n$, assume wlog that $a+b=2$ (unless $a+b=0$, but that case is trivial). Then we just need to prove $a^n+(2-a)^n\ge2$. For the inductive step, note$$\begin{align}a^{k+1}+(2-a)^{k+1}-a^k-(2-a)^k&=a^k(a-1)+(2-a)^k(1-a)\\&=(a^k-(2-a)^k)(a-1)\\&\ge0\end{align}$$completes the inductive step.

Answer (score 1):

Base Case: $n = 1$. We have $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^1 = \frac{a^1 + b^1}{2}$.

Inductive step: Assume for some $k$ the conclusion holds, that is, there exists $k$ so that $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^k \leq \frac{a^k + b^k}{2}$. We show it holds for $k+1$. Note that 
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{k+1} = \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^k\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \leq \frac{a^k+b^k}{2}\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) = \frac{a^{k+1}+a^kb+ab^k + b^{k+1}}{4} = \frac{a^{k+1} + b^{k+1}}{4} + \frac{ab^k + ba^k}{4} \leq \frac{a^{k+1} + b^{k+1}}{4} + \frac{a^{k+1} + b^{k+1}}{4} = \frac{a^{k+1} + b^{k+1}}{2},
\end{align*} as desired. Where the last inequality follows by AM-GM.

Comment: In particular, $a^{k+1}+b^{k+1}-ab^k-ba^k=(a^k-b^k)(a-b)\ge0$.

Comment: Oh that's a nicer way to see it!

Comment: Can you explain how you got to $(a^k-b^k)(a-b)\geq 0$ from the inequality? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n+1} = \left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^{n}\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right) \le \left(\dfrac{a^n+b^n}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)$